# Linked gen_server does not terminate

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have some server

```erlang
-module(trivial).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([
    init/1,
    handle_call/3,
    handle_cast/2
]).

init([]) ->
    {ok, []}.

handle_call(_Msg, _From, State) ->
    {reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.
```

and then I start it from inside of other process that (instantly) terminates:

```erlang
c(trivial).

Before = length([ Proc || Proc <- processes(), is_process_alive(Proc) ]).

Pid = spawn(fun() -> gen_server:start_link(trivial, [], []) end).

false = is_process_alive(Pid).

Before = length([ Proc || Proc <- processes(), is_process_alive(Proc) ]).
```

Unfortunately, the last assertion does not hold: there is +1 alive process. I would assume that `gen_server:start_link` inside of `spawn` created a link, so if the spawned process dies, the server would die as well. Why doesn't it happen? How would I make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because `Pid` has no more instructions to run, so it exits with the reason `normal`, which in this case is silently dropped. You have all the cases in the [doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#receiving-exit-signals)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, changing it to `spawn(fun() -> gen_server:start_link(trivial, [], []), exit(done) end).` did the job.